# What is the fastest way to start a Spring app on Linux?

Tags: java, spring

I have the following Spring program in a file titled `calculator.java`:

```
@RestController
public class Calculator {

    @RequestMapping("/calculate")
    public int calculate(@RequestParam("expression") String expression) {
        // parse the expression
        int result = 0;
        String[] tokens = expression.split("(\\+|-|\\*|/)");
        for (String token : tokens) {
            result += Integer.parseInt(token);
        }
        // return the result
        return result;
    }
}
```

I already tried starting it using `spring run` (I have Spring installed) but it does not work. The documentation is super confusing, what do I need to objectively do to start this calculator.java file with an endpoint accessible in "/calculate" from the browser?

Thank you.

Comment: This class does not have a main method to run. You cannot run just this class on any platform.

Comment: What build system are you using? Gradle or Maven ?

Comment: I tried building with Maven but it failed... I would like to know what are the steps to make this work out of a single file with little hassle

Comment: @plshelpmeout  you can create a maven project in https://start.spring.io/. Noted: you can add dependencies with spring web.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1**: Check out what the Linux domain or IP.

**Step 2**: Check out what the tomcat start port and context path.

**Step 3**: Open you browser input

```
http://{linux domain or IP}:{tomcat started port}/{context path}/calculate?expression=test
```

**Example:**

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/test/calculate?expression=test
```